# Is plunker broken or is it me?

Tags: ionic-framework, plunker

My ionic based [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7GIWSgpFmz1wParkI7he) code was working fine last night but it seems to be broken this morning as no UI items are appearing on the live view. Is this my fault or is it plunker under some kind of maintenance? I have tried to revert to yesterday's versions but still no luck

Here is header of my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check console.

It says

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/7GIWSgpFmz1wParkI7he?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this just changed overnight!

Comment: @kankamuso this didn't change overnight. It is possible that you navigated to plunker over `https` and then opened this plunk. Plunker will preserve the scheme from page to page.

Comment: You are right, @filearts. I meant that happened to me with no apparent reason, not that plunker changed something, and this puzzled me... ;)